# How to delete Prefetch folder in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, windows, prefetch

How to delete Prefetch folder in vb.net? 
I tryed :

kill("C:\windows\prefetch.dll) but it return a error

"Unhandled Exeption"

Comment: `Unhandled Exception`? Try to handle it. Seriously, post the full exception stacktrace. Also is there an `InnerException`? If yes post that too.

Comment: IT ONLY SAY :UNHANDLED EXCEPTION OCOURED!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to delete a file that does not exist!

Clearing Prefetch files could be done in VB.NET like this:
*Imports System.IO

```
Dim file As String
For Each file In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("%systemroot%\prefetch")
System.IO.File.Delete(file)
Next file
```

To avoid geting any error:

```
Try
 Dim file As String
    For Each file In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("%systemroot%\prefetch")
    System.IO.File.Delete(file)
    Next file 
Catch ex As Exception
    msgbox("Can not delete Prefetch right now!")
End Try
```

Well please run your app in Admin Mode (in win7 and 8)

Answer (score 0):

Try
 Dim file As String
    For Each file In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("%systemroot%\prefetch")
    System.IO.File.Delete(file)
    Next file 
Catch ex As Exception
    msgbox("на нах!")
End Try